# Why does aspnet_compiler need write access to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder on my build server?

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler, microsoft-web-deploy

We use a CI server (Jenkins) to compile an ASP.NET project and deploy to our web servers.

I want to precompile the site before deployment to increase performance, so I've set the `PrecompileBeforePublish` property in the Publish Profile (.pubxml).

However, when Jenkins runs the build, the `AspNetPreCompile` task fails with the error:

> AspNetPreCompile:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe
>   -v /
>   -p c:\jenkins\workspace\DeployJob\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source
>   -c
>   c:\jenkins\workspace\DeployJob\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir
>
> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The current identity (JenkinsUser)
>   does not have write access to
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files'.

Note that this is **not** the machine where the web site will be deployed to, it is just a build server. I could grant the current identity (JenkinsUser) access to the *Temporary ASP.NET Files* folder, but I'd rather not have to mess around with filesystem permissions on a box that is just acting as a dumb Jenkins slave.

Is there any way around this? Why is aspnet_compiler trying to write the site to the *Temporary ASP.NET Files* folder, and is there any way to make it use a different temporary directory instead, such as `%TEMP%`?

Comment: No clue why, but this is default behavior. Other then placing a ntfs junction,  don't know of a way to redirect this without changing the standard ASP.NET behavior on the machine.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could play around with this:

```
  <AspNetCompiler ToolPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"  VirtualPath="temp"  PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\Web" />
```

But you're gonna have to give ~some directory the rights.

It's just one of those "live with it" things.........my instructions document for setting up a CI machine has the "give rights to asp.net directory" as you explain.